# How can I delete multiple Facebook Posts on my timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I'm trying to clean my Facebook profile's Timeline, but I don't like the idea of going through them all posts and delete one by one.

Is there any tool, option or something that I'm missing, that allows you to delete multiple posts simultaneously?

> Note: I'm talking about **Timeline posts**, not a Facebook Page as I found [this article](http://www.ogbongeblog.com/2015/09/how-to-delete-all-posts-on-facebook-page.html) mentioning that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. There is no option to delete multiple post simultaneously.

The only option is one post at a time either using the dropdown menu for a post on your Timeline (click the 'V' in the upper right corner of the post) or in your Activity Log click the pencil icon to the right of an item.

Comment: Yeah I opted to start deleting them one by one as I figured it might not be a way to do that :\ it would be a helpful resource tho. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This Chrome extension does exactly what you want:

[Facebook Post Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-post-manager/ljfidlkcmdmmibngdfikhffffdmphjae)